# Rsync include specific sub-directories in hidden directories

Tags: rsync, dot-files

I am trying to use rsync for creating backups of my computer. For this I would like to exclude all hidden directories and files but include specific sub-directories of those hidden directories. As an example, I have the following structure:

```
.hidden_1/
    sub_dir_1/
         sub_file_1
    sub_dir_2/
         sub_file_2
.hidden_2/
    sub_file_3
.hidden_file
normal_folder/
normal_file
```

With this, I would like to copy all normal files and only the sub_dir_1 with all its content. The result should look like this:

```
.hidden_1/
    sub_dir_1/
         sub_file_1
normal_folder/
normal_file
```

I have already tried all kinds of filter settings, so far with no luck. Can anyone help me out here?

Kind regards

valkyrie

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997 & 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270519/rsync-exclude-a-directory-but-include-a-subdirectory/37219769#37219769

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rsync -avh --include='/.hidden_1/' --include='/.hidden_1/sub_dir_1/***' --exclude='/.**' src/ dest
```

- `--exclude='/.**'` Exclude all hidden files and directories relative to the source directory and everything in those directories, i.e. `.hidden_1/` and `.hidden_1/sub_dir_1/`, but not e.g. `normal_folder/.hiddenfoo`.
  The `**` matches anything, including slashes.
- `--include='/.hidden_1/'` Include the `.hidden_1` directory relative to the source directory overriding the exclude rule. It only includes the directory itself, not its content.
- `--include='/.hidden_1/sub_dir_1/***'` Include directory `.hidden_1/sub_dir_1/` and its content. This is equivalent to the two rules `--include='/.hidden_1/sub_dir_1/'` and `--include='/.hidden_1/sub_dir_1/**'`.

Comment: Seeing as rules apply left-to-right could I suggest you put the `exclude` explanation last so that the explanations match the order of processing?

Comment: I find it easier to understand in this order, first exclude everything, then override the excludes. But maybe that's just me...

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you very much. I was missing the include of the first hidden folder.