# Rsync: include specific sub-directories only (using external include-file)

Tags: rsync

I am using rsync with the `include-from="external file"` option. Apart from that my problem is almost identical to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650384/rsync-include-specific-sub-directories-in-hidden-directories).

I want to backup a very specific subfolder, while generally not backup any hidden folders. The only way I managed to do this is painstakingly this way:

```
+ home/*/.config/libreoffice/
+ home/*/.config/libreoffice/4/
+ home/*/.config/libreoffice/4/user/
+ home/*/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu

# hide the rest ( .local, .wine, most of .config ...)
- home/*/.*/
```

Without the 3 initial lines, `registrymodifications.xcu` will be excluded, because its higher-level directories are unmatched until they are “hit” by the very last line... so by my experience I must whitelist them all, piece by piece.

**Is there a less painful way to do this?** (I'd still want to keep all my backup rules in a single, external file...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line, I would do this like so:

```bsh
rsync -ai \
    --prune-empty-dirs \
    --include='*/' \
    --include='home/*/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu/***'
    --exclude='*' \
    "$source" "$destination"
```

This includes all directories, the `registrymodifications.xcu` subdirectory and all files beneath it, recursively, but then excludes everything not explicitly included by other rules.  It also uses `--prune-empty-dirs` (`-m`), which means that empty directories will not be created on the destination.

The effect is that only the files and directories matching the second inclusion rule would actually be transferred.

Or, as a filter file:

```
+ */
+ home/*/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu/***
- *
```

... which you would use as

```bsh
rsync -ai \
    --prune-empty-dirs \
    --include-from=patterns \
    "$source" "$destination"
```

A caveat for this is that empty directories matching the second inclusion rule would *not* be created on the destination, due to the `--prune-empty-dirs` option.

Comment: after `- *` I would need to (finally) add my standard chores (like `/home/*`, `/depot/*` and so on...), but smart solutions with the “directories lever” and then limiting the damage with `--prune-empty-dirs` 

Comment: @FrankNocke `- *` would hide everything not already selected for inclusion or exclusion, so there's no need to hide `/home/*` etc. separately. You can add more rules if you wish, but they would have no effect.